# Rolling sum of all values associated with the ids from two tables BigQuery

Tags: join, group-by, google-bigquery, sum

I have two tables in BigQuery. One table has `date`, `id` and `name` columns. For each name, there are a couple of ids associated with it. The data looks like this:

```
date          id         name
7/11           1           A
7/11           2           A
7/11           3           B
7/11           4           B
```

The other table has `date`, `id`, `comments`, `shares` columns in it. The `id` in this table comes without a name associated to it. The table looks like this:

```
date          id         comments         shares
7/11           1           2               null
7/11           2           4                 2
7/11           3           1                 1
7/11           4           5                 3
```

The end goal is to grab all the ids associated with a specific name (table 1) and sum up the comments and shares for the name or rather for the list of the ids (table 2)
The desired output looks  would look like this:

```
date          name         comments         shares
7/11           A              6              2
7/11           B              6              4
```

Comment: is it mySQL or BigQuery? please clarify!

Comment: Apologies, it is BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join of the 2 tables and aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.name,
       COALESCE(SUM(t2.comments), 0) comments,
       COALESCE(SUM(t2.shares), 0) shares
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.date = t1.date AND t2.id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.date, t1.name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebf6ffc7b12366ebf89a4a9aeb379e28).

Comment: this works as expected! Thank you very much! I now notice that each id for the name is listed five times, hence it is joining five times and the number is five times bigger than it is supposed to be. Is there a way to add a code to just join each id once? I can post a separate question if need be, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Chique_Code you should post a new question where you provide sample data like your actual data and expected results.

Comment: Thank you @forpas I have posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68666837/joining-two-tables-on-id-for-the-first-row-available-sql-bigquery