# joining two tables on id for the first row available SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, row, coalesce

I have two tables that I need to join on date and id. The first table has `date`, `id`, `name` columns. Each name is associated with a couple of ids. The data looks like this:

```
date     id     name  
7/11     1        A
7/11     1        A
7/11     1        A
7/11     1        A
7/11     1        A
7/11     2        A
7/11     2        A
7/11     2        A
7/11     2        A
7/11     2        A
```

The other table has `Date`, `id`, `shares`. It does not have the name associated with the id. The table looks like this:

```
date     id     shares  
7/11     1        5
7/11     2        4
```

The end goal is to get the sum of the shares per name or rather per the list of the ids associated with the name. Here is the code:

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.name,
       COALESCE(SUM(t2.shares), 0) shares
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.date = t1.date AND t2.id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.date, t1.name
```

This works perfectly well, but because table_1 list the same id 5 times, the sum is 5 times bigger than it supposed to be. So I only need to grab the first row from table 1 in the JOIN.
The desired output is this:

```
date     name     shares 
7/11      A          9
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should fix your data model so there are no duplicates.  One option is to remove the duplicates before joining:

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.name,
       COALESCE(SUM(t2.shares), 0) as shares
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t1.date, t1.id, t1.name
      FROM table1 t1
     ) t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.date = t1.date AND t2.id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.date, t1.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fix your underlying data to remove duplicates, it might be a good idea to use CTEs (or a subquery).

```
with 
    table_a as (select * from `project.dataset.table_a`),
    table_b as (select * from `project.dataset.table_b`),
    deduped_a as (select distinct date, id, name from table_a)
select
    date,
    name,
    sum(coalesce(shares,0)) as shares
from deduped_a
left join table_b using(id, date)
group by 1,2
```